# How can i make this listBox items stretch Verticaly?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

__________________________
__________Item1____________
__________Imemnumber2_____
__________Item3____________
__________________________

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <ListBox x:Name="MainListBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionChanged="MainListBox_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel  Margin="10">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="None"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Grid>
```

how can I do that?

____________________________
___________Item1_____________
_________Imemnumber2________
___________item3_____________
____________________________

Comment: what do you mean by stretch vertically ? You showed 2 samples above ? which is the expected result ?

Comment: I'm need to get the expected result. I'm was wrong until formulate this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set the TextAlignment property of the TextBox

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

UPDATE:

Try to fix the width of the TextBlock as shown below

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" TextAlignment="Center" Width="400"/>
```

Comment: You have to give more details in your question, its not clear .. please edit the question and explain clearly what you are expecting

Comment: I would like to make the text of the textblock, regardless of its length formatted center.

Comment: picture link to get the expected result

Comment: "You have not answered any questions"

Comment: @nkchandra has subtlely updated the code line adding a hard-coded Width which may help your problem.

Comment: @Bediente You appear to be new to StackOverflow. Actually I have edited(in other words Updated) the answer. Check it

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" TextAlignment="Center" Width="400"/> It does work.